# Rotating x axis label to vertical from horizontal in JasperReports Charts

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I rotate the x-axis label from horizontal to vertical? The words are too long to be placed horizontally, vertically placing them will be able to display them.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to update your question, indicating that you are refereeing to charts in jasper report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to chart properties, set it to a numeric value in the properties "label rotation" -45.0 for example.